# MongoDB - How to replace from null value with new values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am querying data using the aggregate method in MongoDB, but I have a problem. Specifically, I want to replace the value of the `price` field *(with the condition: if this field value is null)* with the value of `price_option` field in the first item from the `model` field where `stock_count` is greater than 0. How can I do it?

My code to query collection with aggregate:

```js
const doc = await ProductModel.aggregate([    
    ...
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',     
        price: { $first: "$price" },
        model: { 
          $addToSet: {
            price_option: '$model.priceOption',
            currency_unit: '$model.currencyUnit',
            stock_count: '$model.stockCount'            
          }        
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        id: '$_id',       
        price: 1, 
        model: 1   
      }
    }
])
```

My sample data created in collection:

```
{
    "price": null,
    "model": [
      {
        "price_option": "200",
        "currency_unit": "dollar",
        "stock_count": 5 
      },
      {
        "price_option": "350",
        "currency_unit": "dollar",
        "stock_count": 0 
      },
      {
        "price_option": "400",
        "currency_unit": "dollar",
        "stock_count": 2 
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

My desired output is:

```
{
    "price": "200", <= it would be replace by the first item of remaining items where stock_count greater than 0

    "model": [
      {
        "price_option": "200",
        "currency_unit": "dollar",
        "stock_count": 5 
      },
      {
        "price_option": "350",
        "currency_unit": "dollar",
        "stock_count": 0 
      },
      {
        "price_option": "400",
        "currency_unit": "dollar",
        "stock_count": 2 
      },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set` - Create `price_model` field.

   1.1. `$filter` to filter documents in `model` array which has `stock_count` `$get` 0.

   1.2. `first` to get the first document from the result in 1.1.
2. `$project` - Decorate the output documents. Assign `price` field with `price_model.price_option`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      price_model: {
        $first: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$model",
            "cond": {
              $gt: [
                "$$this.stock_count",
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      id: "$_id",
      price: "$price_model.price_option",
      model: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PJj6stvgKkw)

---

For MongoDB version 4.2, you can use [`$arrayElementAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to get the first element of the array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      price_model: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$model",
              "cond": {
                $gt: [
                  "$$this.stock_count",
                  0
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      id: "$_id",
      price: "$price_model.price_option",
      model: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (`$arrayElementAt`)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gxIfnQvmXNs)

Comment: excuse me, what the version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: From MongoDB playground, it is version 5

Comment: But `$first` is only available in the `$group` stage. It not works for Mongo version 4.2.2

Comment: Hi, updated my answer. You can use `$arrayElementAt`.